# Open a pdf file from the file system using swift code

Tags: swift, file, pdf

I saved the pdf file into the phone file system using the code below.

```
func downloadAndSavePdf (urlString:String, fileName:String) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let url = URL(string: urlString)
            let pdfData = try? Data.init(contentsOf: url!)
            let resourceDocPath = (FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)).last! as URL
            let pdfNameFromUrl = "\(fileName)"
            let path = resourceDocPath.appendingPathComponent(pdfNameFromUrl)
            do {
                try pdfData?.write(to: path, options: .atomic)

                print("pdf successfully saved in! \(path)")
            } catch {
                print("Pdf could not be saved")
            }
        }
    }
```

When I try to print out the path after it successfully saved, it is something like `file:///Users/macuser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/088BF978-9DE7-436B-9E4B-FE1879EA806A/data/Containers/Data/Application/AF3216C3-FEFD-42C6-B8CD-DD7347FCF00C/Documents/myfile.pdf`
My question is 
1. I will store this file and path into database and open it later.
2. I could not open the file using the code below.

```
     func openPdfFile(){
        //let pdfView = PDFView()
        let webView = WKWebView()
        let documentDir = FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory
        let userDir    = FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask
        let paths               = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(documentDir, userDir, true)
        if let dirPath          = paths.first
        {

            let pdfURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: dirPath).appendingPathComponent("myFile.pdf")
            //let image    = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageURL.path)
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: pdfURL)
                webView.load(data, mimeType: "application/pdf", characterEncodingName:"", baseURL: pdfURL.deletingPathExtension())
                print("pdf file loading...")

            }
            catch {
                print("failed to open pdf")
            }
            return
        }
    }
```

and the call is

```
openPdfFile()
```

it could not open pdf in web view.  I printed out the path and could open the file in web browser.
Please help!  thank you so much

Comment: Thank Maddy, That is what I thought too, but I am new with Swift.  I am a java guy so you mean open the file in Document folder by FileManager? Do you have a sample code?  The reason I asked because I am confuse between FileManager and PDF reader in Swift.

Comment: `myfile.pdf` and `myFile.pdf` are not the same. Case matters.

Comment: I changed to myfile.pdf it still not working Do we need to init webView as let webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x:20,y:20,width:view.frame.size.width-40, height:view.frame.size.height-40))???

Answer (score 0):

OK it works now.  I need to add WKWebview component 
 to my View Controller .  Then drag it to swift file
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
    The problem now the web view does not spread to entire screen.  I don't know how to detect the screen size and set the web view size accordingly